# Multi-byte I2C read not working while "equivalent" Arduino one does

Tags: i2c, 8051

I understand people have probably asked this before but I've looked around for hours and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get a multi-byte transfer to occur between an i2c device, the DS3231 and my microcontroller, an AT89S51 (8051).

I can get all the data out of it using multiple write/request methods but I would like to learn how to do multi-byte reads/writes so I can simplify my code and get a better understanding of how i2c works.

I've attempted to draw on the image what each portion of the signal does but as it turns out, a mouse isn't the best for this.

The first image is the Arduino equivalent waveform and the second is my implementation.

[image: 8051-i2c-2]
If you compare the waveforms of the Arduino and my 8051, they are fairly similar except for the fact that the Arduino sends back the full 7 bytes of data whereas mine only sends back 1.

At this point, the only thing I think could be wrong is that maybe my 8051 micro doesn't pull the SDA line low enough when it needs to send the ACK signal and so it doesn't get registered by the i2c device. If this is the case, is there a solution to it?

Thank you for your time.

edit: [image]
I deleted the old image and replaced it with one with a better duty cycle.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your images but it looks like the SCL line isn't high for long enough. Also, you should aim for 50% duty cycle (equal high and low times). The SCL line from the Arduino looks much better and is closer to 50% duty cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you somehow don't generate the ACK (SDA low) bit properly after each byte. Since you are the master, you can control the timing. Please study this function that is used to get multiple bytes from the i2c bus. It's the three lines after the for loop that you need to get correct.

```
int I2cGetOctetAndAck(){
    register int result = 0;
    register int i;
    I2C_RELEASE_SDA(); //SDA to Z state, pull-up via resistor
    for (i=0; i<8; i++){ //clock in 8 bits
        I2C_CLOCK_HIGH();
        result <<= 1;
        result |= SDA_PIN;
        I2C_CLOCK_LOW();
    }
    I2C_DRIVE_SDA(); // SDA from Z state to LOW state for generating ACK
    I2C_CLOCK_HIGH(); // SCL HIGH, macro includes delay
    I2C_CLOCK_LOW(); // SCL LOW, macro includes delay
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that worked, cheers. I didn't realise I2C was so sensitive. My code was basically the same as that but I had "I2C_DRIVE_SDA();" after the clock toggling rather than before.

Comment: @Noixo, I2C_DRIVE_SDA after driving clock high would be a START condition and toggling both high and low without driving SDA would be a NAK condition, both would cancel the transfer. Glad to have been of assistance! :)